# How do I kill Symantec Endpoint Protection?

Tags: virus, visual-studio, symantec

I would like to disable Symantec endpoint protection active scan, I am not able to find the pid nor the right task to end in taskmanager. I am using Visual studio 08 with c++ and windows server.

Thanks

edit
that's what I was thinking, I don't really need to even disable Norton, I just need to be able to disable active scan, which you can legally do, if you right click the Norton scanner on windows task pane you have the option to disable it. I want to find a way to programatically do this.

Comment: Nuke it from the orbit, it's the only way to be sure. (I think you need to actually uninstall the software before you can get rid of that, it protects itself exactly against this).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because I am writing a virus pre scanning tool, I want to disable Norton active scan, modify or create a file to contain the EICAR test string and then enable norton again.

Comment: One way is to start the visual studio and attach it to the running process and then simple halt the process

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I close an application using my Program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172378/how-can-i-close-an-application-using-my-program)